# How to flatten dynamic yaml file using java

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I want to parse dynamic yaml files using java into HashMap and access them using dot syntax (i.e "a.b.d")

Given the following example.yml:

```
        ---
a:
  b:
    c: "Hello, World"
    d: 600
```

And can fetch it as

```
 outPutMap.get("a.b.d");

Results:
600
```

Any idea How we can achieve this?

Comment: Yaml is richer than can be represented by a map structure.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Agreed. I have nested keys with dotted format(a.b.d) for which I want to search that in yaml structure and get it's value. And yaml can be dynamic structure, so can't create a class for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thorbjørn said in a comment, a HashMap is probably not the correct data structure for representing a YAML file.

You should try looking into [tree structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) instead.

Maybe something along the lines of:

```java
public class Node {

  private final String name;
  private final Object value;
  private final Node parent;
  private final Collection<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

  public Node(Node parent, String name) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Node getParent() {
    return this.parent;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public Collection<Node> getChildren() {
    return this.children;
  }

  public void addChild(Node child) {
    child.parent = this;
    children.add(child);
  }

}
```

And then you just parse the YAML file line by line and construct nodes as you go, adding all subordinate nodes as children of the closest parent node.

Eventually you'll have a populated tree structure, starting with the top `Node` and going down throughout every `Node` in the tree.

You could then write a method that can parse strings in the dot syntax you want and then navigate the tree structure accordingly to find the wanted `Node`.

Note that it's not a good idea to store the values as `Object`s, you should implement some sort of value-wrapper like NumberValue (that stores the value as a `double`) and StringValue (that stores the value as a `String`), so that you don't have to cast `Object`s to different types.